# Errores múltiples en envío de formulario

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, hosting

Estoy intentando subir un formulario a 000web con PHP pero me da múltiples errores al enviar algo desde el formulario

Estos son los errores que me enseña:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: No address associated with hostname in
> /storage/ssd3/976/19065976/public_html/db.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
> getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in
> /storage/ssd3/976/19065976/public_html/db.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
> given in /storage/ssd3/976/19065976/public_html/registro.php on line
> 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
> given in /storage/ssd3/976/19065976/public_html/registro.php on line
> 15
>
> Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL- Error: in
> /storage/ssd3/976/19065976/public_html/registro.php on line 15

ESTE ES MI CODIGO PHP:

```
/public_html/db.php
<?php
//configuracion necesaria para acceder a la base de datos
function conn(){
$hostname = "id19065976_formulario1"; 
$usuariobd = "id19065976_andres"; 
$passworddb = "Temporal.php24"; 
$dbname = "localhost"; 

// Generando la conexion con el servidor
$conectar = mysqli_connect($hostname, $usuariobd,$passworddb,$dbname);
return $conectar;
}


?>
```

```
/public_html/registro.php
<?php
include_once('db.php');
//Recibo todos los datos del formulario
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$año=$_POST['año'];
$genero=$_POST['genero'];
$director=$_POST['director'];

echo "Los datos son los siguientes: <br>";
echo "$nombre,$año,$genero y $director";

$conectar = conn(); //ejecutar las conexiones a la b.d.
$sql="INSERT INTO peliculas (nombre,año,genero,director)
VALUES ('$nombre','$año','$genero','$director')";
$resul = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql)or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL- Error: ".mysqli_error($conectar), E_USER_ERROR);

echo "$sql";


?>
```

aclarar que es la primera vez que hago una base de datos e intento subirla a un hosting, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Revisa el hostname, alli deberias poner la IP donde esta corriendo la base de datos. Podria ser localhost o 127.0.0.1 si es local. El dbname debe ser el nombre de la base de datos, pero alli tienes el nombre del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa como te dijo Saul el host que es donde deberias tener la ip o dominio destino donde esta la db.
Te recomiendo tambien que no uses ñ para nombres de variables o campos en la base.
El resto del codigo se lo ve bien.

Saludos!